# Both dates are string but strtotime fails on one

Tags: php, date

So when I `var_dump` `$startTime` and `$endTime` I get the following: `string(10) "11-01-2013" string(10) "11-21-2013"`

Great, two strings, lets convert them by doing:

```
var_dump(strtotime($startDate), strtotime($endDate)); exit;
```

What do we get:

```
int(1357887600) bool(false)
```

Um .... that's not right, they're both strings, they're both formatted properly ....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because reading the manual would have provided the answer.

Answer (score 10):

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/strtotime#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Because you're using dashes it's trying to use the European format d-m-y, in which case `11-21-2013` isn't valid.

Comment: Simple method: just replace `-` with `/` in both dates.

Comment: Change your `-` to `/`

Comment: Don't feed the question trolls. Do we really answer by just posting content from the official docs ? .. Next time just close the question. People should atleast put in some effort of their own ..

Comment: @DamienOvereem The answer is kind of buried a ways down the strtotime page. It's an issue that stumped me for a while, even when I was looking at the docs.